# What causes pgbouncer's avg_wait_time to be > 0?

Tags: pgbouncer

The docs describe avg_wait_time as:

> Time spent by clients waiting for a server in microseconds (average per second).

We see occasional spikes in avg_wait_time (normally it's 0). During those spikes, best I can tell, there are available/idle servers. What could be causing the wait time to be greater than 0 in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the flow from [hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-postgres-connection-pooling-with-pgbouncer-unlisted-draft-bdb7ebf073ab#e7a6) leads to that your connection pools are exhausted, and the new connections need to wait until a free spot becomes available for either connecting to a pool, either to get to the executing phase.

> These server connections, that clients get linked to, are
>   “pooled” — limited in number and reused. Because of that it might
>   occur that while client sends some request (beginning a transaction or
>   performing a query) a corresponding server connection pool is
>   exhausted, i.e. pgbouncer oppened as many connections as were allowed
>   it and all of them are occupied by (linked to) some other clients.
>   PgBouncer in this scenario puts client into a queue, and this client’s
>   connection goes to a CL_WAITING state. This might happen as well while
>   client only logging in, so there’s CL_WAITING_LOGIN for that also:
>   [image]

Comment: Not sure that's the case here. During a recent period where the wait time was >0,  `show databases` listed a pool_size of 100 and current connections of 29. If I understand things correctly, doesn't that mean that the pool isn't exhausted?

Comment: The connections might be 29, but if they are all trying to execute a query at the same time in the same pool, and the executing windows are occupied, they have to wait within the pool. Can you see to which pools the users were connected to?

Comment: What's an executing window? The numbers I gave were for a single pool. I'm happy to experiment with different settings. If your theory is correct, what parameter should I adjust?

Comment: Well, imagine you're at the bank. There are 10 people in the lobby, one cashier window is open and 2 people are in the queue for it and the teller is helping someone. The two people in the queue will have to wait for the teller to be finished with helping the customers request.

Comment: Again, what is the setting I can change to test your theory?

Comment: Well, you could change `max_db_connections` to a lower setting, to see if the wait time increases, and increase the `max_db_connections` to see if the wait time decreases.

Comment: `max_db_connections` is currently set to 10000, a number probably 15x what we max out at right now.

Comment: And what is your max_connections setting on the database server itself? Its no use to have a 4 wide lane when it merges to a one lane road further up. Also keep in mind https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140454/increasing-postgresql-9-5-max-connections-to-at-least-300

Comment: That's set to 200, and it appears that pgbouncer never uses more than about 20 server connections.

Comment: Are you running single database instance? If so, some queries that join many tables and require intensive seeks or large writes may lock up access, since the harddisks can only read/write one spot at the time. It could also be that the hdd is used by another process, cleaning up logfiles, backup, etc... When the hdd is busy the server waits.

Comment: Yes, single database. No joins. SSD not HD. But wouldn't server load affect average query time, not average wait time?

Comment: No. If the server is busy writing to disk that 300mb windows update file it downloaded, or writing to disk massive dumps for whatever reason(creation of temp tables too large/complex for RAM) the ssd is dedicated to that writing process. Same goes with any other file creating process on that ssd. Read an explanation https://www.quora.com/Can-an-SSD-solid-state-drive-perform-read-and-write-operations-simultaneously